# Measuring duration of multiple Tasks in C# showing incorrect TimeSpan

Tags: c#, task, stopwatch

I'm attempting to measure the time it takes, roughly, to finish a collection of asynchronous tasks.  My approach is

```
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
stopwatch.Stop();
```

I sit and wait for the operation to finish for over 5 minutes, but the stopwatch will say that 1.5 seconds have transpired.

I also tried:

```
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(task => stopwatch.Stop());
```

...but this still reports that only 1.5 seconds has transpired, but still takes over 5 minutes to run.

`tasks` is a variable of type `IEnumerable<Task<T>>`.

I'm struggling on finding a way to diagnose this and was hoping I could get some help.  Thanks!

## Update

Here is a more complete example:

```
public async Task<BulkOperationResponse<Source>> BulkInsertSourceDocumentsAsync(IEnumerable<Source> documents)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Beginning bulk insert...");

    var tasks = new List<Task<OperationResponse<Source>>>(documents.Count());
    tasks.AddRange(documents.Select(document =>
        _orderStatusesContainer.CreateItemAsync(document, new PartitionKey(document.CUSTACCOUNT))
            .CaptureOperationResponse(document)));

    var response = await ExecuteTasksAsync(tasks);

    return response;
}
```

```
public async Task<BulkOperationResponse<T>> ExecuteTasksAsync<T>(
    IReadOnlyCollection<Task<OperationResponse<T>>> tasks)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"Executing {tasks.Count} tasks");

    // TODO: This seems to be reporting the wrong time
    // Opened an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/53193
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    stopwatch.Stop();

    _logger.LogInformation($"Finished {tasks.Count} tasks in {stopwatch.Elapsed}");

    return new BulkOperationResponse<T>
    {
        TotalTimeTaken = stopwatch.Elapsed, // TODO: Confirm time is correct.
        TotalRequestUnitsConsumed = tasks.Sum(task => task.Result.RequestUnitsConsumed),
        SuccessfulDocuments = tasks.Count(task => task.Result.IsSuccessful),
        Failures = tasks.Where(task => !task.Result.IsSuccessful)
            .Select(task => (task.Result.Item, task.Result.CosmosException)).ToList()
    };
}
```

In my test, I'm importing 400,000 documents, and they all complete successfully after 5 minutes.

Comment: What exactly takes 5 Minutes? Stepping over the await with the debugger? Or is there something more involved?

Comment: Bear in mind that `WhenAll` is taking a set of `Task`s that *have already been started* by something else. Depending on how you're obtaining these `Task`s, a lot of work may not be measured

Comment: Each task is a CosmosDB operation, and if I put a break point on or after the `stopwatch.Stop()`, the `stopwatch.Elapsed` property reports 1.5 seconds of a `TimeSpan`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I'm updated my question with more specifics

Comment: I see your point about the stopwatch not starting completely before any of the tasks start.  But 1.5 seconds vs. 5 minutes when the `Task.WhenAll(...)` is called seems like there is something else going on considering I `ExecuteTasksAsync` pretty quickly after assembling the task collection

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but where do the tasks get started?

Comment: I might be missing something too.  There isn't anything else to show in my case, but they definitely get executed.  I'm calling `CreateItemAsync` for each document using the V3 of the Cosmos .NET SDK, and I'm following this documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-migrate-from-bulk-executor-library#execute-operations-concurrently.  Executing your import tasks in this way allows the SDK to manage doing those tasks in bulk, partitioned by the partition key of the document.  But I figured it isn't about the SDK and more about not using `Stopwatch` correctly?

Comment: Be aware that the code before first real async call (http/db/disk) is actually executed synchronously. That's mean, when you create tasks to `await` you probably call some method (in linq `Select`?), if this method has CPU bound work to do before first real async call it will be executed before you start your timer and this work won't be measured.

Comment: `ExecuteTasksAsync` is misnamed. That's my point. By the time you call it, the tasks have already been started and done arbitrary amounts of work. Exactly how much they do is an implementation detail of `CreateItemAsync` - it's the thing that creates and starts the tasks running and, very possibly, does the bulk of the work before returning the `Task` to you.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, that is definitely something that could be going on, thanks for the insight.  I'm guessing one possible solution would be to start the `Stopwatch` before assembling the tasks, and maybe pass in the `Stopwatch` instance into the `ExecuteTasksAsync` method (after changing its name ;-) ).  But I'm worried about that API.  The method couldn't "trust" that the stopwatch wasn't started too early or not started at all.  Is there another way to get what I'm after?

Comment: That's definitely what is going on.  The `Stopwatch.StartNew()` isn't invoked until the majority of the work is done.

Comment: You could have it be passed a `Func<IReadOnlyCollection<Task<OperationResponse<T>>>>` that it calls to "create" the tasks that the caller can then provide. But you still have to trust the caller won't just have pass you back a collection they created before calling your method or run arbitrary code as well as creating the tasks.

Comment: I will update this with what I learn from folks who can update the documentation.  Here is the ticket on GitHub: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/53193